# Capture Session Timeout in SAP cloud foundry application

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, app-router

Iam developing a SAP CF app and wnated to capture session timeout and show pop-up to user before session timeout happs to either refresh the session or execute the logout ,but setting the env variable  SESSION_TIMEOUT as given in the link is also not working neither central logout is triggered : 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/0aac697f0cf7444193ed5eb0fc6e5bd0.html#loio0aac697f0cf7444193ed5eb0fc6e5bd0__section_blz_hgn_mv

cf set-env  SESSION_TIMEOUT 1

it is not triggering the central logout endpoint configured in xs-app.json. My client initiated central logout is working as expected.

please help with any suggestions and pointers ,my requirement is to capture central logout event on session expiry and show popup to user to either refresh the session or execute logout but this is not working in SAP Cloud foundry environment ,please help.

Comment: Where did you add the `SESSION_TIMEOUT` variable? According to the documentation it is preferred to have it set to the same value on both, your application and the approuter.

Comment: its added under env variable of app as per the guide ,at app-router level its not supported as per documentation section: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/5f77e58ec01b46f6b64ee1e2afe3ead7.html#loio5f77e58ec01b46f6b64ee1e2afe3ead7__section_imh_gsy_lv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for the HANA XS advanced model, which I think is different to the approuter used on Cloud Foundry. Therefore, I'd assume that the documentation won't help you much.

Adding an environment variable to your app alone won't do much either, I fear. Unless you tell your app to do something with that.

Bottom-line: I think you need to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: thanks Dennis but the help link talks about xs advance router ,which is the same we use for SAP cf router correct me if iam wrong if yes pleas provide link for sap cf router ,also where i can found the xsuaa session timeout configuration to understand what is the default config ,platform should provide flexibility for configuring such variable for cf apps as its important feature in my opinion,some thig is given for sap cloud portal but not for cloud platform in cf .

Comment: i had to implement custom mechanism to implement this but thanks for your help Dennis

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I have no experience about this.

But the link provided (https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/5f77e58ec01b46f6b64ee1e2afe3ead7.html#loio5f77e58ec01b46f6b64ee1e2afe3ead7__section_imh_gsy_lv) is about the app router configuration.

It says,

> The sessionTimeout property is no longer available; to set the session time out value, use the environment variable .

Therefore, I would try to set the environment variable for the app router as well, e.g., via the `manifest.yaml`.